# IMAP works on my localmachine but not on shared hosting

Tags: php, email, ssl, imap, shared-hosting

I'm connecting via imap to an email account:

```
$hostname = "{imap.zoho.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}";
$imap = imap_open($hostname, 'email', 'password');
```

And it works perfectly fine from XAMP on my local machine, but when I run it from my shared hosting account (host-ed.net) I get the following errors:

> Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
>   {imap.zoho.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert} in
>   /home/****/public_html/testmail.php on line 4
>
> Warning: imap_num_msg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /home/****/public_html/testmail.php on line 5
>
> Warning: imap_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /home/****/public_html/testmail.php on line 27

Any idea what could be the issue with my hosting provider that is causing this?

**edit**...

Added imap_errors and get this (timing out):

> map_errors(): Array ( [0] => Can't connect to imap.zoho.com,993:
>   Connection timed out )

Comment: Have you tried returning [imap_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-errors.php)? Even though it says `Warning: imap_open(): ...` it was suggested [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php#107414).

Comment: Contact the hosting company. They may have outbound firewalling, preventing the connection. If you have shell access on the shared host, you may try opening a port with telnet like `telnet imap.zoho.com 993`

Comment: Test whether you can make a connection to the server:  openssl s_client -connect imap.zoho.com:993.

Comment: Thanks, I've contacted the hosting provider and they have sorted it out. I think they may have been blocking port 993

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
imap_open("{imap.mail.eu-west-1.awsapps.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "EMAIL", "PASS");
```

This was written for AWS WorkMail. You can check this documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php

This is all that you need.